# Covert a List<string> to IDataReader

Tags: c#

I've to perform a bulk insert from an Azure function and I was wondering if there's a way of treating an `IList<string>` as `IDataReader`. As I've seen there're around some implementations that via reflection creates an `IDataReader` but I don't know how to process it when it's a string (`';'` separated value)

Thanks.

Comment: What about converting the `;` separated string into a `List<string>` and then doing what you're saying

Comment: I need to use them in a SqlBulkCopy that accepts an IDataReader ...since the source can be huge (1-2GB  of source file) I wish to not have a copy in memory of the data

Comment: The correct answer in the duplicate is *use ObjectDataReader*. What you try to do though is *not* what the title says. An IDataReader is *not* a method of parsing strings. If you want to parse the string, well, parse it first, then send it to the database. Parsing does *not* mean loading everything in memory.

Comment: In fact, this looks like a case of the XY Problem. You have a problem X, assume the solution is Y and ask about Y when you get in trouble, instead of X. Where does the data come from? What is the actual size and format? Do you *really* get 2GB data *at once* ? Or do you receive events that you save into 2GB files?

Comment: Is the file a delimited file with `;` as the field delimiter? Or a line-delimited JSON? Why not read the file a line at a time, parse individual lines into concrete objects and feed *that* IEnumerable to ObjectDataReader? You don't need to load the entire text in memory

Comment: @advapi so this *is* an XY problem indeed, you already asked the *actual* question, didn't provide enough information, then asked *again* with an attempted solution Y, but still no schema info